# C++ auto deduction of return type

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I want to write a function that return different types based on different input as below.

```
enum MyType
{
    A,
    B
};

template<MyType T> struct MyStruct
{

};

static auto createMyStruct(MyType t)
{
    if(t==A)
        return MyStruct<A>();
    else
        return MyStruct<B>();
}
```

It didn't work out because there are two return types for one auto. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Templates are expanded at compile time. You do a run-time decision. This cannot work.

Comment: That means that I have to do a lot of if else...

Comment: @Michael I think you can use `dictionary` instead of `ifelse`.

Comment: or use common parent struct type (inheritance)

Comment: Can you provide usage of `createMyStruct()` function?

Comment: Describe what you try to solve. I smell bad design here.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely no way of having a (single) function that returns different types based on a runtime decision. The return type has to be known at compile time. However, you can use a template function, like this (thanks to @dyp for making me simplify the code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

enum MyType
{
    A,
    B
};

template<MyType>
struct MyStruct {};

template<MyType type>
MyStruct<type> createMyStruct()
{
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    auto structA = createMyStruct<A>();
    auto structB = createMyStruct<B>();

    std::cout << typeid(structA).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << typeid(structB).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: but what if `MyStruct` has arguments in constructor?

Comment: @gomons If the number of arguments are the same, then probably replacing `{}` by `{arg0, arg1, etc}` should do, see live [here](http://ideone.com/czmm5u). If they have different number of arguments, then probably you need 2 functions, overloaded via enabled_if like I mentioned in my previous edit.

Comment: Actually, I don't see any reason write `auto structA = createMyStruct<A>();` instead `MyStruct<A> structA;`

Comment: @gomons that was the initial question, how to create a function that returns different types (otherwise OP could from the very beginning just create the structures via direct declarations)

Comment: @gomons actually even if the number of ctor arguments are different in A vs B, you can just specialize the function `createMyStruct` for each type, so there's no need for more complicated design.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn [abstract factory design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern).

For use objects of type `MyStruct<A>` or `MyStruct<B>` you need common interface.

Common interface provided in abstract base class.

```
struct MyStruct
{
    virtual ~MyStruct() {}
    virtual void StructMethod() = 0;
};

struct MyStructA: public MyStruct
{
    void StructMethod() override {}
};

struct MyStructB: public MyStruct
{
    void StructMethod() override {}
};

std::unique_ptr<MyStruct> createMyStruct(MyType t)
{
    if (t==A)
        return std::make_unique<MyStructA>();
    else
        return std::make_unique<MyStructB>();
}
```

Comment: it's better to return a `std::unique_ptr` from a factory, since you return a rvalue, and can easily bind it to a `shared_ptr`.

Comment: @vsoftco, Can you fix it? I rarely use `std::unique_ptr`

Comment: just replace `std::shared_ptr` by `std::unique_ptr` and `make_shared` by `make_unique` (C++14) or simply by `return unique_ptr<MyStructA>();`

Comment: @vsoftco `return unique_ptr<T>()` returns an empty unique pointer.

Comment: @dyp, sorry, typo, need `unique_ptr<MyStructA>(new MyStructA)`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to write code like this:

```
void foo (MyType t) {
    auto x = createMyStruct(t);
    //... do something with x
}
```

You are attempting to derive the right type for `x` at runtime. However, the return type of a function must be known at compile time, and the type resolution for `auto` is also determined at compile time.

You could instead restructure your code to be like this:

```
template<MyType T> struct MyStruct
{
    //...
    static void foo () {
        MyStruct x;
        //... do something with x
    }
};
```

The idea is to write a single `foo()` function whose only difference is the type of thing it is manipulating. This function is encapsulated within the type itself. You can now make a runtime decision if you have a mapping between `MyType` and `MyStruct<MyType>::foo`.

```
typedef std::map<MyType, void(*)()> MyMap;

template <MyType...> struct PopulateMyMap;

template <MyType T> struct PopulateMyMap<T> {
    void operator () (MyMap &m) {
        m[T] = MyStruct<T>::foo;
    }
};

template <MyType T, MyType... Rest> struct PopulateMyMap<T, Rest...> {
    void operator () (MyMap &m) {
        m[T] = MyStruct<T>::foo;
        PopulateMyMap<Rest...>()(m);
    }
};

template<MyType... Types> void populateMyMap (MyMap &m) {
    PopulateMyMap<Types...>()(m);
}

//...
    populateMyMap<A, B>(myMapInstance);
```

Then, to make a runtime decision:

```
void foo (MyType t) {
    myMapInstance.at(t)();
}
```